# Reading from a file - Java

Tags: java, io, filereader

I am working on a project where I need to read text from a file and then store particular parts as variables.

Say I had the text file example.txt

```
John
Smith
32
1991
```

I would want to assign the first line as:

```
String firstName; -> John
```

and so on.

I have this so far.

```
public void load(String fileName){
   BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This code will print the contents of the file, which is a step in the right direction, but how to go about reading per line?

As I don't really want to get into the habit of storing whole files in memory.

I know you can convert the text with

```
parseInt()
```

and similar methods but I'm just trying to get my head around extracting values.

Comment: Is each element on it's own line?  (ie `John` is on it's own line, `Smith` is on it's own line, etc)

Comment: Yes, I thought it would make the learning easier.

Comment: If items were on the same line would you not have to get the String length then break it apart?

Comment: If they were on a single line, you could use deliminator to separate them and then and use `String#split`, but that comes down to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like...

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String firstName = sCurrentLine;
    String lastName = br.readLine();
    String age = br.readLine();
    String dob = br.readLine();
}
```

But this makes quite an assumption about the file requirements, it assumes that there are 4 lines per entry.

You could place each entry on it's own line and use a deliminator to separate them, for example

```
John;Smith;32;1991
```

And then use something like...

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String parts[] = currentLine.split(";");
    String firstName = parts[0];
    String lastName = parts[1];
    String age = parts[2];
    String dob = parts[3];
}
```

to read each entry.  This gives you a little more control over processing the entries, as you can check the length of `parts` array to validate that it has the number of expected values.

Once you've got an entry, you'll want a better way to manage each entry, I'd create a simple POJO to hold the values, maybe something like...

```
public class Person {

    private final String fisrtName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final int age;
    private final int dob;

    public Person(String fisrtName, String lastName, int age, int dob) {
        this.fisrtName = fisrtName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getFisrtName() {
        return fisrtName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

}
```

Then you might be able to use `List` or `Map` to store them, which would make it easier to manage...

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>(25);
//...
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String parts[] = currentLine.split(";");
    String firstName = parts[0];
    String lastName = parts[1];
    String age = parts[2];
    String dob = parts[3];
    people.add(new Person(firstName, lastName, Integer.parseInt(age), Integer.parseInt(dob));
}
```

Another solution might be to use a `Scanner`, which would allow you to use `next` and `nextInt` to parse each entry

So, if we re-structure the to the following format...

```
John Smith 32 1991
```

You could simply use

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(sCurrentLine);
    String firstName = scanner.next();
    String lastName = scanner.next();
    int age = scanner.nextInt();
    int dob = scanner.nextInt();
    people.add(new Person(firstName, lastName, age, dob);
}
```

instead

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. You've not only answered my question but gone further, by providing alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too.

```
   File file = new File("your file location");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        //Assign to your pojo
        System.out.println(scan.next());
    }
```